# List of tuples to list of first elements in that list of tuple C#

Tags: c#

In `Dictionary` I can get a list of its `Key`/`Values` like in the below code:

```
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    List<string> list_of_first_elements = new List<string>();
    list_of_first_elements = new List<string> (dictionary.Keys);
```

Is there an attribute/method can do same with `List<Tuple>` without looping over the list and add its first/second elements?         Something like that:

```
        List<Tuple<string, string>> list_of_tuples = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        list_of_first_elements = """SomeCode""";
```

Comment: Using Linq: list_of_first_elements = list_of_tuples.Select(_ => _.Item1).ToList()

Comment: There's no such method. You can use LINQ, but it will still enumerate all elements, which is essentially a loop.

Comment: In terms of performance it will be nearly the same. So I prefer LINQ as it seems more clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @KlausGütter and @2kay mentioned I used LINQ to do that and its performance is nearly to looping over the `List` but it's certainly more clear, and here is the code:

```
list_of_first_elements = list_of_tuples.Select(_ => _.Item1).ToList();
```